# OpenVPN (NordVPN) not allowing route through other VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

This is technically a cross-post from [a post I made on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1317084/openvpn-alongside-l2tp-vpn), because I wanted to get some other opinions. If you take a peek at that post you can see that I have two VPNs. A personal VPN from NordVPN, which is basically a OpenVPN TAP-network under the hood, and a L2TP VPN, which I use solely for connecting to one IP address.

The route table looks pretty sound, but it seems that OpenVPN is blocking the connection to the IP routed through my L2TP VPN. I ran Windows network diagnostics and surprisingly found some interesting information:

```
Details about network security diagnosis: 

Settings that might be blocking the connection:
Provider name:      openvpn firewall provider
Provider description:   openvpn firewall provider
Filter name:        OpenVPN Interface leak protection
Provider context name:  -
```

I'm assuming that this "filter" is on the OpenVPN server. Does anyone know of a way to really force the route to the L2TP VPN? Perhaps I would need to use the OpenVPN client instead of the NordVPN client to tweak such configurations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://www.vpnuniversity.com/learn/how-to-fix-every-vpn-ip-leak), NordVPN supports a kill-switch feature for protecting your privacy.
I think they install a [Windows filter driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/filter-drivers) to achieve this and this driver makes sure only traffic going through the NordVPN tunnel is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that OpenVPN is trying to prevent other connections as part of a 'leak protection' service.  Crafty websites can prompt your browser to make connections otherwise than through your VPN tunnel to reveal('leak') your direct IP address or identifiable etc.  This can also happen with DNS requests so various solutions implement some kind of protections to block such traffic.  In your case you perhaps want this particular traffic to be permitted even when running *almost* all your internet traffic through OpenVPN.

Consider if the inability to connect to the L2TP host only when OpenVPN is active/connected and if your OpenVPN connection is configured to 'tunnel all' or with a route that looks like 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0.